# C# LINQ Generic Extension Method to check if sequence is the same and return it's value

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I am trying to put together an extension method that will allow me to check if all values of a sequence are the same, and if so return that value, or if not return an average of that value if its an int or double or return a concatenation of that value if it is a string.

For example take the following object and a list

```
public class Item
{
    public int Size {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

var itemsTheSame = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { Size = 1, Name = "Red" },
    new Item { Size = 1, Name = "Red" },
    new Item { Size = 1, Name = "Red" }
};
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
itemsTheSame.AllEqual(item => item.Size)); // should return 1 as an int
itemsTheSame.AllEqual(item => item.Name)); // should return "Red" as a string
```

My generics are not very strong, but this is what ive started off with

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int AllEqual<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, int> selector)
    {
        if (!list.Any()) return default(int);
        var first = list.First();
        return list.Skip(1).All(selector == first) ? default(int) : default(int);
    }
}
```

It's quite obvious to me that the return type needs to be generic aswell, so came up with this (doesent compile)

```
public static TReturn AllEqual<TSource, TReturn>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TReturn> selector)
{
    if (!list.Any()) return default(TReturn);
    var first = list.First(selector);
    return list.Skip(1).All(selector == first) ? default(TReturn) : default(TReturn);
}
```

I am completely confused as I need to be able to pass `Func<TSource, TReturn> selector` to the `.First()` to be able to get the value itself, but `.First` needs a `Func<TSource, bool>`. I also need to be able to pass the same selector to `.All` as I only want to check the field specified in the selector for equality.

Is this even possible or am i better off having a set of overloaded methods, one that returns an int and the other that returns a string etc ?

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wHWVoa)

Comment: This sounds a bit confused. e.g. what's the average of "Red"?

Comment: You could have your method signature to be `public static TSource AllEqual<TSource>...`

Comment: @stuartd seeing as TSource would be typeof(string) in this scenario i would want it to return a concatenation of the distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to avoid iterating the `IEnumerable` multiple times. It could be too expensive, you never know.
2. You need an implementation for each numeric type because of the average feature.
3. Average is actually the same whether you have all the same values or not. Just use the `Average` extension method instead. You may want to wrap it to make the syntax the same. (Or consider to give it a different name, like `AllEqualOrAverage`, because it doesn't do the same.)
4. The average of an `int` is usually a `double`. Decide whether you want to round it, use floor or actually return a `double`.
5. You need `Select(selector)` to get the values from the items. The argument of `First` is a predicate, as in `Where(predicate)`.

Proposal:

```
// for doubles (returning average or default if list is empty)
public static double AllEqual<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, double> selector)
{
    // use IList<T> interface to quickly check the size of the
    // list if this interface is available. Use ToArray otherwise.
    var ilist = list as IList<TSource> ?? list.ToArray();
    if (ilist.Count == 0) return 0.0;
    list.Select(selector).Average();
}

// for ints (returning average or default if list is empty)
public static double AllEqual<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, int> selector)
{
    // use IList<T> interface to quickly check the size of the
    // list if this interface is available. Use ToArray otherwise.
    var ilist = list as IList<TSource> ?? list.ToArray();
    if (ilist.Count == 0) return 0.0;
    list.Select(selector).Average();
}

// for everything else (returning unique value or default)
public static TReturn AllEqual<TSource, TReturn>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TReturn> selector)
{
    // put 2 distinct values into an array
    var distinctItems.Select(selector).Distinct().Take(2).ToArray();
    if (distinct.Length == 1) return distinct[0];
    default(TReturn);
}
```

Note that this only works if you know the numeric type at compile time. If you need to return the average of a number which is only recognized at runtime (it is an object at compile time), it gets really hard.

Comment: Performing `Distinct` before computing the average completely messes up that average.

Comment: I knew and also said this. It is fixed now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`First` doesn't accept a selector, it accepts a predicate.  To apply a selector to the first item you need to get the first item (using its parameterless overload), and then invoke the selector on that result.

And to compare objects of an unknown type for equality you won't be able to use the `==`operator.  It is bound at compile time, so it couldn't account for the specific implementation for that type, in addition to the fact that it might not have one.  You should use an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare the items for equality (you can use the default comparer if none is provided).

Also note that your implementation iterates the source enumerable up to 3 times.  That could easily be a problem if it's actually a query, and not an already materialized collection.  You're really better off just iterating the sequence explicitly, rather than using LINQ operations here, since you can't do it with just one LINQ query.